# Get data from oracle with php

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to develop website using php but I have two servers:

*one for php files

*other one for database (oracle)

so I'm trying to get data from database using following connection string

```
$dbstr=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=xxx.xx.x.xx)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=BHDB)
    )
  )
    global $objConnect;
    $objConnect = oci_connect('building', 'building', $dbstr, 'AL32UTF8');
if (!$objConnect) {
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
```

but in oci_connect the file can't display any thing in php (blank page)

but I don't know the problem

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: how I can do this

Comment: Your error logs are located on your web server. If you do not know how to access them please contact your system administrator for details.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);  // In PHP 5.3 use E_ALL|E_STRICT
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

to your script and check the errors.

You can simplify your connection string to:

```
$dbstr='xxx.xx.x.xx/BHDB';
```

I get the impression you haven't read the [Underground PHP & Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

Comment: Judging by the reaction to your decade-old [comment on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.oci8.php) not many people RTFM.  Since it's an official Oracle publication, and the OCI8 extension is maintained and recommended by Oracle, maybe you could suggest a change to the PHP manual to explicitly link it as recommended reading (rather than just as a comment)?